# MATLAB class array

Tags: performance, arrays, matlab, oop

What would be the best way to manage large number of instances of the same class in MATLAB?

Using the naive way produces absymal results:

```
classdef Request
    properties
        num=7;
    end
    methods
        function f=foo(this)
            f = this.num + 4;
        end
    end
end

>> a=[];  

>> tic,for i=1:1000 a=[a Request];end;toc  

Elapsed time is 5.426852 seconds.  

>> tic,for i=1:1000 a=[a Request];end;toc  
Elapsed time is 31.261500 seconds.
```

Inheriting handle drastically improve the results:

```
classdef RequestH < handle
    properties
        num=7;
    end
    methods
        function f=foo(this)
            f = this.num + 4;
        end
    end
end

>> tic,for i=1:1000 a=[a RequestH];end;toc
Elapsed time is 0.097472 seconds.
>> tic,for i=1:1000 a=[a RequestH];end;toc
Elapsed time is 0.134007 seconds.
>> tic,for i=1:1000 a=[a RequestH];end;toc
Elapsed time is 0.174573 seconds.
```

but still not an acceptable performance, especially considering the increasing reallocation overhead

Is there a way to preallocate class array? Any ideas on how to manage lange quantities of object effectively?

Thanks,
Dani

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This solution expands on [Marc's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276198/matlab-class-array#276530). Use **repmat** to initialize an array of RequestH objects and then use a loop to create the desired objects:

```
>> a = repmat(RequestH,10000,1);tic,for i=1:10000 a(i)=RequestH;end;toc
Elapsed time is 0.396645 seconds.
```

This is an improvement over:

```
>> a=[];tic,for i=1:10000 a=[a RequestH];end;toc
Elapsed time is 2.313368 seconds.
```

Answer (score 5):

Coming to this late, but would this not be another solution?

```
a = Request.empty(1000,0); tic; for i=1:1000, a(i)=Request; end; toc;
Elapsed time is 0.087539 seconds.
```

Or even better:

```
a(1000, 1) = Request;
Elapsed time is 0.019755 seconds.
```

Answer (score 2):

`repmat` is your friend:

```
b = repmat(Request, 1000, 1);

Elapsed time is 0.056720 seconds


b = repmat(RequestH, 1000, 1);
Elapsed time is 0.021749 seconds.
```

Growing by appending is abysmally slow, which is why mlint calls it out.

Comment: The problem: 

b = repmat(RequestH, 1000, 1);

b(1).num=99;

b(2).num

ans =

    99

Comment: That's the nature of a handle class.  It's fundamentally a singleton class, so all "instances" actually point to a single instance.  I was just showing the speedup.  Weather to use a Handle class or not is a very separate question.